# MySql Permission to Use Field in Condition but NOT to Read

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to give a MySql user permission to use a field in the WHERE condition but not to read it.
e.g.:

```
SELECT (example_field) FROM example_db.example_table WHERE secret_key = 123
```

-Thats okay, you can use secret_key in conditions!

```
SELECT (example_field,secret_key) FROM example_db.example_table WHERE secret_key = 123
```

-Thats illegal, you don't even need to read secret_key's!

Sorry for the possibly stupid question but this seems to me like the first type of permission that pops in one's mind!

(Sorry if my MySql syntax is incorrect, I prefer staying high level :) )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this cant be done via MySQL standard privileges system. If you can use a field in a WHERE condition, you can read its value. This is handled by SELECT privilege (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html).

**Why it is not a good solution**

This is understandable : if one had the ability to use a field in conditions but not to select it directly, he could finally guess value, after n steps :

By brute force :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value = 1; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value = 2; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value = 3; -- 0
-- ...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value = 123; -- 1 ! FOUND
```

By dichotomy, assuming secret value is contained between 0 and 1000 for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 500; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 250; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 125; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 75; -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 112; -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value >= 118; -- 1
-- ... you get it
```

Other method using LIKE (could also work for strings) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value LIKE '1%'; -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value LIKE '11%'; -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value LIKE '12%'; -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id = 321 AND secret_value LIKE '121%'; -- 0
-- ...
```

So we can say that after a certain number of steps, with the ability to do conditions, we can get the value anyway.

**What you can do**

You could define a field which will contain a **hash** of your secret_key (let's say secret_key_hash).

From Wikipedia :

> A cryptographic hash function is a mathematical algorithm that maps
>   data of arbitrary size to a bit string of a fixed size (a hash
>   function) which is designed to also be one-way function, that is, a
>   function which is infeasible to invert. The only way to recreate the
>   input data from an ideal cryptographic hash function's output is to
>   try a large number of possible inputs to see if they produce a match.

For example, [SHA1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) is a hash function implemented in MySQL.

If you give access to a hash of the secret key instead of the secret key itself, it gives the ability to check if `SHA1(123) = secret_key_hash` but it does not allow to get the secret_key value.

**If your secret_key is a password**

- Learn good practices before developing your system
- You should never record it in clear text (store only hashes)
- Fast hash algorithms like SHA1, MD5... are not designed to hash passwords and should be avoided in this case. Please consider using BCRYPT or another algorithm provided for. If you use PHP, this page can be interesting : http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and suggestions! I'll consider using a hashing algorithm (Fortunately I'm not dealing with any personal information.) It still feels like it would make it a bit more secure though.